# simple way to count up in a Wicket-Iteration?

Tags: wicket

**Is there a way, to simply count up in a wicket iteration? Or do I need to get this through the java class?**

What I would like to get is;

`<spans>` with class `input-no-1`, `input-no-2`, `input-no-3`, ...

from something like this (the %COUNT% is of course symbolic for what I need)

```
<div wicket:id="mygroup" class="my-form-slider">
    <wicket:container wicket:id="choices">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" wicket:id="radio"/>
            <span class="fancy-input input-no-%COUNT%" wicket:id="fancyLabel"></span>
        </label>
    </wicket:container>
</div>
```

(I am the Frontend guy here, very limited wicket knowledge.)
— Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could override onComponentTag method of Label as below:

```
@Override
        protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
            tag.put("class", "fancy-input intput-no-" + countVar + "");
        }
```